# Which order does the else statement follow?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I wanted to be sure about something,

When i have multiple `if/else` conditions and `if` does not imply an `else` condition for one of those `if` conditions; does the next `else` statement goes for the last `if` statement?

For example:

```
if(condition1)
{
    //operation1
}

if(condition2)
{
    //operation2
}

else
{
    //operation3.  
}
```

Like above example, if i don't use an `else` for the first `if` statement, which `if` statement does this `else` work for? Would this cause a problem for me, if i don't specify the `else` for each `if`?

I made some tests but wanted to be sure about how does this works actually.

Comment: The correct answers aside, another pair of `{}` and another indent would make sure neither you nor some other person will ever be confused about this. ;-)

Comment: What @DevSolar says.  Have a downvote for not bothering to format/indent clearly.

Comment: @MartinJames Is there a reference for the question formats? as i'm new here and don't know actually what's the wrong.

Comment: @MartinJames: I severely disagree with downvoting for that reason. The OP might be looking at legacy code trying to reverse-engineer the author's intent. In any case the question is clear and to the point. Downvoting? I don't think so.

Comment: @DevSolar anyone attempting reverse-enginering would either 1) not have posted this question becasue they are highly skilled and understand how else is bound to if, or, 2) Doomed because they are too incompetent to complete their assigned task.

Comment: I'm surprised anyone is complaining about the indentation of this code.  Aside from eliminating the blank line between the 2nd `if`'s block and the `else`, and *maybe* indenting the comments in the blocks, it looks perfectly clear to me.  I think for most people it's obvious which `if` the `else` goes with, and an extra set of `{}` just to indicate that would look awkward rather than helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Standard, p 6.8.4.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4.1)

> An else is associated with the lexically nearest preceding if that is allowed by the syntax.

So, in your example, the `else` pertains to the 2nd `if` (the one with `condition2`).

Comment: Thank you for the quote and the answer, for all of you. I got it!

Answer (score 3):

In C (and other C-like programming languages), you can place additional accolades to make statements more clear. Your code is equivalent to:

```
{
    if(condition1) {
        //operation1
    }
}

{
    if(condition2) {
        //operation2
    } else {
        //operation3.  
    }
}
```

The `else` statement is bounded to the second `if` statement. It means that the program will first evaluate `condition1`. If `condition1` holds, it will execute `operation1`. Next **regardless of the result of the first test**, it will test `condition2`. If `condition2` holds, it will execute `operation2` and otherwise it will execute `operation3`. The else always binds with the nearest `if` (bottom-up) that is not yet bounded that is not yet bounded by an `else`, or using curly braces as brackets for another binding policy.

Comment: Coding it this way also makes it clear what will happen if somebody edits the code to delete condition2 but somehow forgets about the else condition. It avoids the surprise of condition1 picking up an unwanted else.

Answer (score 2):

> if i don't use an else for the first `if` statement, which if statement does this `else` work for?

Second `if` statement.
The rule is that `else` will go with the nearest `if` in case of multiple `if`s.

C11 §6.8.4.1/3:

> An `else` is associated with the lexically nearest preceding `if` that is allowed by the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The else statement is bound to the last if statement. The first if statement doesn't have an else due to the second if statement

Answer (score 2):

An `else` statement must always directly be followed after an if statement (or it's block). So your `else` in the example would affect `if(condition2)`.

Answer (score 2):

The closest. An else is associated with the lexically nearest preceding if that is allowed by the syntax.

```
if(condition1)
{
//operation1
}

if(condition2)
{
//operation2
} else {          // <<<<
//operation3.  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the `C11` standard, chapter §6.8.4.1, *`The if statement`* (*emphasis mine*)

> An `else` is associated with the **lexically nearest preceding `if`** that is allowed by the
>   syntax.

So, your `else` statement is bound to ***lexically nearest preceding*** `if` statement, which is the `if(condition2)` statement.

Answer (score 2):

The 'else' is always attached to the nearest 'if'. In other words, the last else is paired with the last if.

It is best for readability to use curly braces and proper indentation.

Answer (score 2):

always else is related to its preceding if statement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to do exactly ? but you could use the if /else if statement of you could use a swtich.

```
example if-else:

      if(condition 1)
      {
        // your code here
      }
      else if(conditition2)
      {
         //your code here
      } 
      else
      {
        // your code here
       } 

or a swtich:
var caseSwitchLastName = "De Waard"
var caseSwitchFirstName = "Pieter";
switch (caseSwitchFirstName)
{
    case Pieter:
       Console.WriteLine("His name is Pieter");
       break;
    case Sander:
       Console.WriteLine("His name is Sander");
       break;
    default:
       Console.WriteLine("His name is de Waard");
       break;
}
```

both codes have the same output. Only the examples are less typing.

Answer (score 1):

There are three different types of selection statements.

Single Selection Statement (if)

- It performs an action only if the condition is true

Double Selection Statement (if...else)

- It performs an action if the condition is true and another action if the condition is false

Multiple Selection Statement (Switch)

- Performs different actions based on the possible values of constant internal expression

In your case the first if is single selections statement and when it reaches the end of block } it will continue the sequential processing of the following statements in the program.

Since your else is right after your second if therefore it makes this statement a double selection statement. Which perform the action in if block in case the result is true and the action in else in case the result is false.

Answer (score 0):

The else is for the last if that is before the else.

you can see more here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control

Good luck!